# Initialize serial port with x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, serial-port, nasm, x86-16, bios

I want to use the serial port `COM1` without using the BIOS interrupt 14h, and for this purpose I am following the tutorial at [osdev](https://wiki.osdev.org/Serial_Ports) but I have some problems during the initialization. (I am pretty new to asm and to bios related stuff so my code may be very wrong or may be there is a need to initialize other things before I can initialize the serial port)

My current code looks like this, and should be a direct translation of their C code.

```
%macro outb 2
    mov dx, %1
    mov al, %2
    out dx, al
%endmacro

%macro inb 1
    mov dx, %1
    in al, dx
%endmacro

    bits 16
    org 0x7c00 ;; set the origin at the start of the bootloader address space

    xor ax, ax
    mov dx, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

serial_init:
    outb [com1+1], 0x00 ;; disable all interrupts
    outb [com1+3], 0x80 ;; enable DLAB (set baud rate divisor)
    outb [com1+0], 0x03 ;; Set divisor to 3 (lo byte) 38440 baud
    outb [com1+1], 0x00 ;;                  (hi byte)
    outb [com1+3], 0x03 ;; 8 bits, no parity, one stop bit
    outb [com1+2], 0xc7 ;; enable fifo, clear them, with 14-byte threshold
    outb [com1+4], 0x0b ;; IRQs enabled, RTS/DSR set
    outb [com1+4], 0x1e ;; set in loopback mode, test the serial chip
    outb [com1+0], 0xae ;; test serial chip

hang:
    jmp hang

com1:
    dw 0x3f8

    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55
```

I have some debugging primitives and everything, seems to go smoothly until the line `outb [com1+0], 0x03` afterwards, if I read the line control register `[com1+5]` I get an error but I am not to sure how to interpret it (it seems to be an error related to stop bits, error 3)

Comment: `mov dx, [com1+1]` will not give you `dx==0x3f9` if that's what you were expecting.

Comment: What you want is probably something like `com1 equ 0x3f8`, and then `outb com1+1, 0x00`, etc.

Comment: `word [com1]` = `3F8h`, `word [com1 + 1]` = `3`, `word [com1 + 2]` = `0` and so on.

Comment: Also you didn't initialise `ds`. The `mov dx, ax` is presumably a typo for `mov ds, ax`

Comment: @Michael, `[com]` was `0x3f8` and I blindly thought that I could add one to it to get `0x3f9` where as it were legal I should have written `[com]+1`, I did not know about `equ` I applied both of your recommendation and everything worked perfectly fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the *outb* macro definition, NASM will expand your `outb [com1+1], 0x00` macro invokation into:

```
mov dx, [com1+1]
mov al, 0x00
out dx, al
```

Because of the square brackets, the first instruction will load `DX` from memory, and sadly that does not contain the intended port address (0x03F9)! What you get is 0x0003, composed from the high byte of the word stored at *com1* and the next byte in memory that happens to be 0 because of the `times` zero-padding.

In your defense, the wiki article https://wiki.osdev.org/Serial_Ports does use square brackets when it says that you should send data to e.g. `[PORT + 1]`. However those brackets have nothing to do with the same brackets used in the assembly programming language.

The C code snippet is clearer. It has `define PORT 0x3f8` which in assembly becomes `PORT equ 0x03F8`. And the `outb(PORT + 1, 0x00)` instruction becomes `outb PORT + 1, 0x00` in assembly. This time NASM will expand your *outb* macro into these 3 instructions:

```
mov  dx, PORT + 1    ; Same as `mov dx, 0x03F9`
mov  al, 0x00
out  dx, al
```

The C code given for reference:

```c
#define PORT 0x3f8          // COM1
 
static int init_serial() {
   outb(PORT + 1, 0x00);    // Disable all interrupts
   outb(PORT + 3, 0x80);    // Enable DLAB (set baud rate divisor)
   outb(PORT + 0, 0x03);    // Set divisor to 3 (lo byte) 38400 baud
   outb(PORT + 1, 0x00);    //                  (hi byte)
   outb(PORT + 3, 0x03);    // 8 bits, no parity, one stop bit
   outb(PORT + 2, 0xC7);    // Enable FIFO, clear them, with 14-byte threshold
   outb(PORT + 4, 0x0B);    // IRQs enabled, RTS/DSR set
   outb(PORT + 4, 0x1E);    // Set in loopback mode, test the serial chip
   outb(PORT + 0, 0xAE);    // Test serial chip (send byte 0xAE and check if serial returns same byte)
 
   // Check if serial is faulty (i.e: not same byte as sent)
   if(inb(PORT + 0) != 0xAE) {
      return 1;
   }
 
   // If serial is not faulty set it in normal operation mode
   // (not-loopback with IRQs enabled and OUT#1 and OUT#2 bits enabled)
   outb(PORT + 4, 0x0F);
   return 0;
}
```

> if I read the line control register `[com1+5]` ...

Accuracy will be key in programming this hardware. It's even true for programming in general.
The *line control register* (LCR) is at 03FB (PORT + 3).
The *line status register* (LSR) is at 03FD (PORT + 5).